# Why did my remote server's identifier change after switching my modem/router?

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I installed ubuntu server 22.04 on an old laptop I had lying around, just to get the hang of things. I plugged in this laptop to my modem/router through the ethernet port. I use MobaXterm from my windows laptop to ssh into the remote server. I set up a session on MobaXterm with the name of my remote server and my username, and log in to my server.
Last week, I changed my modem/router because I switched ISPs. The WiFi was set up OK, and I connected the remote server to the router again through ethernet as before, but this time, I was not able to ssh into my server. When I typed in `ssh myusername@servername`, I saw:

`_ssh: Could not resolve hostname servername: Name or service not known`

I used `arp -a` on MobaXterm to identify the devices on my network, and was able to identify the IP address of my server, and then log in, using `ssh myusername@IPaddress`. This would not have been a major problem, if not for the fact that I also have RStudio server installed on my server, and where previously I would type `http://servername:8787` to open RStudio Server in my browser, I now have to type `IPaddress:8787`.

Basically, I want to understand:

1. Why this behaviour occurred
2. What I should have done before switching modems to ensure my working setup was undisturbed.
3. What can I do to refer to my server using its previous name again, instead of its IP address.

Thanks for any advice and help!

Edit: After getting my internet service fixed and logging in to my modem/router, I discovered that my server (`kvhome`) is, in fact, recognized by the network and is part of the LAN. Reading around on this site and other sites, I looked up the hosts file at `/etc/hosts`, and this is what it has:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 kvhome

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

So it looks like my server is indeed being recognised, but is being given a secondary status (sorry if I am not explaining that correctly, I am just thinking aloud here). So does my issue have anything to do with editing the hosts file? How can I correct it without causing some more issues?

Comment: This is a modem/router issue … Login to its management interface and insure that both hostname resolution/translation is enabled and that your server’s hostname is picked up/identified correctly in the modem/router then you might need to restart the router .

Comment: @Raffa, Thanks for your comment! I found that I am not able to login to the modem management interface. I am having a new modem/router installed by the company. I will check and get back as soon as I have the replacement modem in place.

Comment: Different modems use different subnets for the home network. Most common ones are `192.168.0.0/24` and `192.168.1.0/24`. You have not said if you had assigned static IP address for the server. For example, you may have assigned `192.168.0.20` to the server. If the new router uses `192.168.1.0/24` subnet, then that assigned static IP address is now outside the subnet, and is not valid.

Comment: Ubuntu uses Avahi. That means you should add `.local` at the name of your server. For example, `ssh myusername@kvhome.local`.

Comment: @user68186, thanks for your responses. I have not assigned any static address to the server, at least not that I can remember doing. And about your second comment: `ssh myusername@kvhome.local` also does not work, I still see the error message `_ssh: Could not resolve hostname kvhome.local: Name or service not known`. 

Upon logging in to my router, I see this: 
`Start IP address 192 . 168 . 1 . 11
Stop IP address 192 . 168 . 1 . 254`. 
Is that what you meant by the assigned subnet? How can I fix this?

Comment: Never mind. The problem is probably somewhere else if you did not assign a static IP.